# Column or global variable not found db2

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a issue with DB2.

I have two libraries with the same structure database. The only one difference is the data.

When i try this sql request for the first library, it's work

```
SELECT *
FROM Z24FR.CLIENT, Z24FR.EMPLOYE
WHERE CLIENT.CLINUM = EMPLOYE.CLINUM
```

but when i try with the other library, i have this error.

```
SELECT *
FROM Z24UK.CLIENT, Z24UK.EMPLOYE
WHERE CLIENT.CLINUM = EMPLOYE.CLINUM
```

```
Column or global variable CLINUM not found.
CLINUM was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, CLINUM is not a column of any table or view that can be referenced.
```

I check the CLIENT and EMPLOYE tables and they have the column with data.

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Well... DB2 disagrees with you. Can you access the `Z24UK.CLIENT` and `Z24UK.EMPLOYE` tables using another visual tool to check they both actually have column `CLINUM`?

Comment: I'm surprised the first one  doesn't fail the same way, if you qualify a table with it's schema in `FROM` clause then you have to use 3 parts qualified name for columns, like `Z24FR.CLIENT.CLINUM`, is this select the effective query that runs ? [see](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ambiguity-table-designators)

Comment: @TheImpaler i use DBeaver and they both have actually column CLINUM

Comment: I would try the tables separately: 1) `select CLIENT.CLINUM from Z24UK.CLIENT;` and 2) `select EMPLOYE.CLINUM from Z24UK.EMPLOYE`. What do you get with these queries?

Comment: @nfgl well, whit "Table designators" when i try this `SELECT * FROM Z24UK.CLIENT a, Z24UK.EMPLOYE b WHERE a.CLINUM = b.CLINUM`, IT'S WORKS ! Thanks you

Comment: @TheImpaler with 1 and 2, i have the same error

Comment: @nfgl do you have any clue why the first query work, but the second, except if the solution ?

Comment: no both should behave the same to me.

Comment: @nfgl If you are using dBeaver, and executing the two in separate tabs, with differing connections, One may have system naming, and the other sql naming. The behavior described above (with the three part name) is only present in sql naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you qualify columns depends on the way tables are "declared"

see [Table designators](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ambiguity-table-designators)

So if you want something common you can code

```
SELECT *
FROM Z24xx.CLIENT CLIENT, Z24xx.EMPLOYE EMPLOYE
WHERE CLIENT.CLINUM = EMPLOYE.CLINUM
```

Or because comma notation is old and not really readable

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Z24xx.CLIENT CLIENT
  inner join Z24xx.EMPLOYE EMPLOYE on CLIENT.CLINUM = EMPLOYE.CLINUM
```